# Nix: How to override stdenv.cc with overlay globally?

Tags: nix, nixos, nixpkgs

I would like to override `stdenv.cc` to a specific GCC version (not necessarily in nixpkgs) globally using an overlay (i.e. without changing nixpkgs). Is there a way to do that?

An overlay like this causes an infinite recursion (since package `gcc49` has `stdenv` as input):

```
self: super:
{
  stdenv = super.overrideCC super.stdenv super.gcc49;
}
```

What is the correct way to change the `stdenv.cc` globally?

Setting manually `stdenv = ...` in `import nixpkgs` is not feasible, since I would like to replace the `cc` not only when building/using nix expressions but also in e.g. `nix-shell -p package`.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

```
(import <nixpkgs> { overlays = [(self: super: { gcc = self.gcc10; })]; }).stdenv.cc
```

This returns a derivation for gcc-10.1.0, so it could work.